# Ubuntu 15.10 | Unity Freezes After Escaping Full-Screen Video

Tags: unity, 15.10

Since clean installing Ubuntu 15.10, Ubuntu occasionally freezes when I press ESC while watching full-screen videos and has frozen once when I was editing a video in Openshot recently. During most of these freezes, my entire session becomes unresponsive except for the mouse; the only way I can reclaim my session is to either reboot or switch to a virtual terminal and enter `kill -9 -1`. Other times, all but the mouse and Unity launcher becomes unresponsive, and I could unfreeze everything else simply by launching a program.

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Is there anybody else experiencing the same issues?

Comment: After I upgraded to 15.10, exiting fullscreen flash video sometimes killed my Xorg. Logs tell stuff about failing to setup intel_drm. Interestingly, since I removed flashplugin and put pepperflash the issue vanished.

Comment: I also am seeing this when I switch apps from running Kodi full screen.  The entire session gets locked up and doesn't accept any mouse or keyboard input.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for replying. I disabled flash in my browser and I haven't had any freezing issues lately.  Even a separate issue with Google Chrome tabs becoming unresponsive has stopped. I will keep you posted should any freezing occur.

Answer (score 4):

Unity was crashing for me when switching from full screen Kodi. I didn't have the flashplugin installed. Instead I fixed the issue by installing and running CompizConfig Settings Manager and disabling Effects->Fading Windows.